# verify content control's ContentPlaceHolderID attribute in the content page

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I am a new ASP.NET developer. I am making development using C#. I removed some default contents from that I am getting these error notification as attached in screen shot can anybody look at and give me a solution also some one inform me from where .NET pages control header and footer so I can make modification there.

[image: Screen Shot]

Here is the complete error heading text:

> "Cannot find ContentPlaceHolder 'MainContent' in the master page '/Site.Master', verify content control's ContentPlaceHolderID attribute in the content page."

Comment: in you child page you are referring to the deleted content via `MainContent`. Search and fix it.

Comment: You should read about "using master page in asp.net"

Comment: @VMAtm where `MainContent` is exist, is this file name or folder and what thing i need to change?

Comment: `MainContent` is ID of ContentPlaceHolder exist in Master Page

Answer (score 2):

Remove `asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent"` from your child pages or Add `<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server">` into your Master page.

Comment: I have code like this `<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Width="194px"></asp:TextBox>
</asp:Content>`

Comment: then add this to your master page `<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server">`

Answer (score 2):

There is no ContentPlaceHolder named 'MainContent' in your master page,

A content place holder should be in your Master page like this:

```
 <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server">

    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
```

And child pages like this:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you have a child page that inherits from  a master page ContentPlaceHolder should match between them.

So if you masterpage declare that every child should fill its  `Box1` `Box2` and `Box3`containers every 
child page that is linked to it (`MasterPageFile="~/MasterPages/Site.master"`) must contain this references `<asp:Content runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="Box1">` even if empty.
In your case you have declared a box name that Master page doesn't has

**update**

looking at your code I can suspect that you have linked the master page in a wrong way.
Change the attribute of your page and be sure that the path is correct

```
MasterPageFile="~/MasterPages/Site.master"
```

if it doesn't work try this

If the page is empty delete it and recreate aspx page with master page, after you select the master page the child page will be created with the right contentplaceholders.

Comment: I have code like this `<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Width="194px"></asp:TextBox>
</asp:Content>` in Default.aspx

Comment: giving an error "Error 1 The file '/MasterPages/Site.Master' does not exist. C:\Users\user123\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\WebSites\WebSite3\Default.aspx"

Comment: do you have nested masterpages?

Comment: can ou please told me how can be a masterpage? is master page mean Default.aspx also there is a site.master and under that site.master.cs i don't know what these are can you please explain?

Comment: sure, you should have a master page with contentplaceholders. they have a property ID that must be exactly the same of the contentplaceholderid property of the content element in child pages. If you have ID property equals is wrong. To refer a box from child page use ContentPlaceHolderID property. In your master page you should have `<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server">`